# Adding a new row to a selection of rows in vba

Tags: vba, excel

New to VBA!

I have a spreadsheet split into sections and for each section there is an 'Add new line' where it adds to the existing rows in that section.

I've had a go at the Currentregion function that counts the rows but stuck on selecting the last row then adding one underneath.

The code so far is the counting bit where I can return the number of rows already in the section:

```
Dim numberOfRows As String

numberOfRows = Range("A:A").Find(sBudgetLine, LookIn:=xlValues).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2
```

However, I'm struggling to find the next step of adding the additional row.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: @Matt Cremeens just edited my question, thanks. sBudgetLine is the name of the section and is passed into the method, this code is what I've been starting on, I'm using currentregion to skip the section header and column headers of the section - hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why is numberofRows a String?  Should be an integer if you plan on using it as a cell reference.

```
Dim NumberofRows as Integer

NumberofRows = Cells(1,1).End(xlDown).Row + 1

Rows(NumberofRows).Insert
```

Comment: sorry typo - was trying to find the proper value location e.g. B292

Comment: If you want to find the cell address, like "B292", then you would use .Address at the end of finding your cell.  For example, SomeCell=Cells(292,2).Address would return a string of "$B$292".  You can't mix the two methods.  In the case where you are only identifying the row number you would use an integer.  Are you looking to add a whole row or insert a single cell in a column?

Comment: Ahh ok, I'm looking to add a whole row underneath existing rows

Comment: I edited my answer with a replacement for the code you have.  This assumes you have a column of contiguous data.  If there are blanks in your column and nothing below your column, I prefer to use NumberofRows=Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row